# How to hide a text input's browser-generated dropdown list of previous items

Tags: html, autocomplete

When I generate a text input like this:

```
<input type="text" name="name" />
```

When I start to type, the browser will display a dropdown list below the text input. This list contains the values I previously used for this text input in this browser. I want to generate my own autocompletion via ajax.

How do I tell the browser with either css or javascript to not generate this dropdown list.

If this task is easier by using jquery, I would prefer such a solution.

Comment: input elements aren't dropdown lists.  perhaps you're thinking of select elements? I'm sorry, but I don't really understand what you're asking.

Comment: I mean the browser generated autocompletion for this text input.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Both IE and Firefox (maybe others, I didn't research it much) support the [autocomplete attribute](https://wiki.mozilla.org/The_autocomplete_attribute_and_web_documents_using_XHTML).  If you set it to "off" these browsers will no longer display the autocompletion.

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" />
```

Comment: Outdated, does not work with newer browsers.

Comment: @DamirOlejar Got some data to back that up? http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-autocomplete-onoff

Comment: Confirmed in your link now: browsers are increasingly ignoring or overriding this command, on purpose.

Comment: <input type="password" autocomplete="off" /> is not working